# Getting 404 after Update in Multisite

Tags: multisite, updates, upgrade, network-admin

we have a multisite install width the following structure:

http://domain.com/pages/myblog

Where "pages" is blog 1.

Other site in the network have domains like:

http://anotherdomain.com/pages/blog

All works fine. We can reach every site in the network and work on it.

If we make an update, all sites point to the main site "***://domain.com/pages/" and not the domain which was set in the backend.

This happens only after the upgrade. The htaccess, Domain Mapping or the sunrise.php are not being changed during the update.

Deactivating all Plugins, also does not help.

I did not make the install.

Does anybody have an idea, what the issue could be?

Many Thanks in avcance,
Lars

Answer (score 0):

If you're using caching, turn it off. Make sure your .htaccess is correct, and turn off all your plugins. 
For more detailed info [Click here](http://wisdmlabs.com/blog/solve-404-error-wordpress/)

Comment: We do not use caching. The htaccess it the same like before, when it worked. The link you sent me did not help. Like I said: before the update, all worked fine.Any other ideas?